# onCreate Intent Strait to URL without seeing a User Interface

Tags: android, android-intent

Ok, so I am new to Developing any kinds of Apps and have limited programming experience but I am trying to show my team a basic android app that skips strait to a website. I figured out the onCreate and using Intent. At this point I am trying to skip the UI completely (where it opens a blank screen with a title). I know everyone says to use webview but the site we are sending the users to is not specifically made to be mobile friendly but does work in on the Chrome mobile browser. Also the users I deal with are very basic and if I can just have them press one button and it takes them to something familiar, it is the best option.

Currently this is what I have:

```
public class Launcher_Some_Website extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String url = "https://www.google.com/";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"));
        startActivity(i);
```

The app has been tested and is working like this. I am have tried to search for my answer but I am probably not using the correct key words.

I know there are websites to make these apps but I need a very bare bones app and need to know exactly what code is in the apk. The purpose is to show that the app does not have to be complex and that it is an option. I will work on making the app more secure once I can make it do what I said I could make it do.

Comment: After a user launches your app, instead of opening app UI, do you intend to open the URL in browser on the mobile phone?

Comment: Yes. The intent is to go directly to a Browser to a website, as it does not currently support webview on the website, but does work in the current build of Chrome on the device.

Comment: What if the default browser isn't Chrome?  Something to think about.  And if it's "working like this" then what's the problem?

Comment: was just wondering if there was a way to remove the screen that pops up before it jumps to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible but you can make better UI via progress dialog until web site open.You can use AsyncTask for this. That code works for me ;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new OpenSite().execute();

}

private class OpenSite extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

You can delete `thread.sleep(2000)` if you don't want to wait.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.